# Using html button to change status of data

Tags: html, django, forms

I'm building an ecommerce site with django, and i wanted to create a button that would signal that an order had already been delivered.

[image]

I'm pretty sure you can acheive this with a checkbox, but i wanted to use a button, because it would be easier to click when using a tablet.

I want the button to also be "unclickable" in case someone accidentally clicked a button for a wrong order.

Do i need to make a form in the html? or is there an easier way to do it.

this is my html:

```
Order page

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td>Order</td>
        <td>Order Quantity</td>
        <td>Delivered</td>
    </tr>

    {% for ord in orders %}
        {% for food in ord.orderitem_set.all %}

        <tr>
            {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
                <td>{{ord.pk}}</td>
                <td>{{ord.user.first_name}}</td>
                <td>{{ord.user.email}}</td>
                <td>{{ord.user.get_profile.phone}}</td>

            {% else %}
                <td colspan="4"></td>
            {% endif %}

                <td>{{food.name}}</td>
                <td>{{food.quantity}}</td>

            <td>{% if forloop.counter == 1 %} <button type="button">Delivered</button> {% endif %}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

</table>  


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should make a hidden input for each row that represents the button status. Use your favorite javascript library to toggle the button text from Delivered/Not while adjusting the hidden input from True/False

Answer (score 1):

hmm, I think just putting a form around the button would be the "easier way" ^^

later if you wanted to, you could make it a spiffy javascript toggle using almost the same view code below maybe

e.g. around your buttons...

```
<form action="{% url show_orders %}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="order-id" value="{{ ord.pk }}"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="action=" value="toggledelivery"/>
    <button type="button">{% if not ord.is_delivered %}Not {% endif %}Delivered</button>
</form>
```

then in your view, something like...

```
def show_orders(request):

     if request.method == "POST": 
         order_id = request.POST.get('order-id', None)

         # TODO toggle the order here

         return HttpResponseRedirect(back_to_the_order_admin_page)
     else:
         # ...show the admin page
```

Comment: why is method Get and not post?

Comment: when i click the button it doesnt do anything.  do i need to make the button be of type "submit"?